# Is any way in nhibernate to merge rows from select into one field

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, nhibernate

This query will work perfectly in SQL Server:

```
SELECT ',' + name 
FROM temp1
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

But I need to implement it using C# & NHibernate without database orientation.

```
return new { Items = Items..(
    Entities = String.Join(", ", x.Main.Select(z => this.ShortName))
```

This will create a separate query for each row of the top query, and that is very expensive in terms of performance.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a view in the database and use nHibernate to map to the view instead of the table?

EDIT:
another option is HQL, as @Amit Joshi suggested. this might look like this (untested):

```
var items = session.CreateQuery("SELECT ',' + name FROM temp1 WHERE XML PATH like '' ")
                   .UniqueResult<Item>();
```

more info on HQL might be found [here](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/readonly.html#readonly-api-querycriteria) or [here](https://nhibernate.info/doc/reference2-0en/query-syntax.html)

Comment: Yes, I can, but the code will depend on the DB, which is not very good..